# How can I fit a face plate to two devices in separate single-gang boxes?

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

I ran into an issue when changing an outlet and switch in what I thought was a double gang box.  After opening it up I found it was 2 single gang boxes next to each other.  The previous switch and outlet (non-GFCI) fit in there fine so I thought no big deal and replaced them.

Well after replacing them I found that my wall plate is a ways off from being able to fit.  Has anyone ran into an issue like this before?  Is there a way to make this work?  I would prefer to not have to cut them both out and put in a double gang if at all possible.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did the cover plates work before?  Can you put the GFCI device somewhere upstream instead?

Comment: Looks like the top would fit if the switch was mounted squarely. It's nearly at the right horizontal position at the top (though the bottom is out). I'd swap the whole works out for a double remodeler box, personally.

Comment: @Harper Here is a picture of the old one.  It didn't need to line up as nicely because of the style of outlet.  [Picture here](https://i.imgur.com/cTsH7LP.jpg)

Comment: @isherwood Yes, I think the top worked but as you can see the right box has an angle on it so the bottom ends up being too out of whack.  Not sure on measurements but is a 2 gang around the same size as two single gangs?  Obviously I can't patch up if it is short by too much and the wall plate can't cover it.

Comment: Does a pair of pliers make the boxes come together a little better? (take the GFCI out and squeeze the hell out of 'em). Hammer and flat head might 'convince' them to be closer. However, either of these approaches can pop the tile. - You could *not* put the screw in the switch in the lower spot... not ideal, but it'd be GFCIed so w/e right? ;) especially if it has a ground wire. Or you could do it right, like the guy with 100k says.

Comment: I've seen installations where the side edges were cut off of two faceplates.  Requires some care to get a neat fit, but it can be done.

Answer (score 5):

The gap you are seeing is well within the normal limits of adjustment for standard yokes (the metal thing the screws go through).

You just tightened down the yoke screws and let them land where they may.  You'll need to back them off, shift the outlet and switch around as needed, and repeatedly try the plate until it lines up.

If the yokes don't give you enough horizontal slack in their slots, you may need to change to different devices that do.

If all else fails, roll back to the original receptacle and switch, figure out from where this location is supplied, and install the GFCI there with this part of the circuit on the LOAD terminals. If there's already a GFCI there, then this one is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while on this, but I've recently been searching for the same info so I thought it could be helpful to others.

Go online to Kyle Switch plates and search for "wide-spaced 2 decora rocker switch plates for 2 single boxes". They have exactly what you need and lot of other weird configurations, too.

Good luck.

Comment: When mentioning a specific product/brand, it is expected that you disclose your affiliation with the company. Please [edit] your answer to let us know, even if it's just "happy customer".